# Angular2 ng-for performance issue

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have seen performance issue in angular2 ng-for, when rendering a long list. I have tried with an array object of length 300. Is there any solution to resolve it.

Angular2.0.4.rc
Ionic2 beta11

Comment: `prodMode` or `devMode`? build output or dynamically built in the browser?

Comment: It's in prodMode. iOS browser and iOS hybrid app. Dynamically built.

Comment: Safari mobile is know to have performance issues. Using virtual scrolling and not showing that many items at once is probably the way to go.